# One mapbox map is freezing when two maps load on a same fragment but on a different frame

Tags: java, android, mapbox-android, mapbox-marker

We are getting the below error when trying to load two Mapbox maps in a fragment.

**Can't update annotation: Symbol{geometry=Point{type=Point, bbox=null, coordinates=[-121.3559284, 38.9228032]}, properties={"symbol-sort-key":null,"icon-size":null,"icon-image":"marker-icon-id","icon-rotate":165.30766,"icon-offset":null,"icon-anchor":null,"text-field":null,"text-font":null,"text-size":null,"text-max-width":null,"text-letter-spacing":null,"text-justify":null,"text-radial-offset":null,"text-anchor":null,"text-rotate":null,"text-transform":null,"text-offset":null,"icon-opacity":null,"icon-color":null,"icon-halo-color":null,"icon-halo-width":null,"icon-halo-blur":null,"text-opacity":null,"text-color":null,"text-halo-color":null,"text-halo-width":null,"text-halo-blur":null,"id":2,"custom_data":null}, isDraggable=false}, the annotation isn't active annotation.**

We have a fullscreen mapview on the screen, and on the right bottom, we have a small window for video. Using the symbol manager, we are showing current lat long on the map. It's working fine, and the symbol is moving properly once the application is loaded. When we click on the video, we get a full-screen video instead of a mapview, and a mapview instead of a small video. On that mapview we can also see the moving symbol with the current lat long. But when we click on that small mapview again, the full screen mapview is showing and the moving map icon is getting frozen.

Please see the reference below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check whether your annotation is present in the symbol manager. If it isn't there, add it in symbol manager first, then update that annotation.

```
if (!symbolManager.getAnnotations().containsValue("Your symbol"))
{
    SymbolOptions symbolOptions = new SymbolOptions();
    symbolOptions.withLatLng(newLatLng);
    symbolOptions.withIconImage("image");
    Your symbol= symbolManager.create(symbolOptions);
}
```